# Shell Script + Write to File a String

Tags: shell

I have a string

server.ip=192.168.1.200

And I need to write the above statement completely into the file.

How can this be done?

This is what I'm trying to do...

```
set client_config = xmlrpc_server.properties
echo 'serverurl=http://'${IP}':8000' >> %${client_config}%
echo 'port=/RPC2' >> %${client_config}%
```

It doesn't get added to the file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me

```
$ FOO="192.168.1.1"
$ echo "serverurl=http://$FOO:8000" >> x.conf
$ more x.conf
serverurl=http://192.168.1.1:8000
```

I'm using zsh. I verified it with bash as well. What's the problem you get when you do this?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.9(3)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)

Comment: `more` is not essential. I simply used it to display the contents. Also, what kind of system doesn't have `more`?

Comment: Just FYI `echo` adds newline character to the output file.
If you don't want it use `printf` command it only writes the string to file and will not append newline character

Comment: @DmitryTokarev Correct. You can also use `echo -n`.

Answer (score 5):

`echo 'server.ip=192.168.1.200' > file` in BASH.

Comment: When I makle the file name a variable, I get an error when trying to do this "ambiguous redirect"

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
set filename=yourfile.txt
echo server.ip=192.168.1.200 >> %filename%
type yourfile.txt
```

If you need that line to be appended into a file. Note that double `>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
client_config = xmlrpc_server.properties
echo "serverurl=http://${IP}:8000" >> $client_config
echo "port=/RPC2" >> $client_config
```

The above mentioned stuff worked. Thanks for the help folks!!

Comment: What shell are you using? the first line should not work  in any Borne Compatible shell. Instead of: client_config = xmlrpc_server.properties you should ommit spaces, and write: client_config=xmlrpc_server.properties. Otherwise, you are trying to execute "client_confi" command with first parameter "=" and second parameter "xmlrpc_server.properties"